# Oracle - in that I need to add a column and to add valus in that column

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to add a column and to add values to that column in an Oracle table

I have tried this:

```
alter table sms
add (Split_Count int);


insert into SMS (Split_count)
values(8120);
where S_NO=1;
```

Comment: And what is the question?!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want good answers, you need to post good questions. It is not obvious from your question what is the problem - an error, incorrect result, ... ? Please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to add a new column to an existing table and then you want to add values to this column so that it will not be NULL anymore. I propose you to use UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE sms
SET split_count=8120 WHERE S_NO=1
```